# python multiprocess will auto exit

Tags: python, multithreading, join, process, exit

I'm sorry my english is very poor,but I will try to explain it simply.
My situation is every process I use Tkinter create a dialog.And then create a class name engine which create 6 threads then engine class use t.join() wait the thread exit.

```
import threading
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from engine import Engine
import settings

class Controller(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.run_list=[False,True]
        self.run_sqe=0
        self.engine_is_running=False

    def run(self):
        self.is_running=True
        self.is_update=self.run_list[self.run_sqe]
        settings.S_is_update=self.is_update

        self.eng=Engine(settings.S_target_website)
        self.eng.start()

        self.run_sqe+=1
        if self.run_sqe>=len(self.run_list):
            self.run_sqe=0

        self.engine_is_running=True
        self.eng.join()
        if self.is_running:
            self.run()

    def stop(self):
        self.eng.is_running=False
        self.is_running=False
```

The question is I start 4 python processes like that.All processes's code almost the same.
When I start that 4 processes at the same time,one or two of them will shut down in the random time,maybe after 1 hour or 3 hours even later.I let all the process and thread print some word when it quit,but it didn't print anything when they shut down,just like it suddenly shut down rudely.

The machine's cpu always use 90% even higher,I think maybe the python because of that so it shut down some process,or the reason is the threading.join() didn't work.
I use activepython2.6 32-bit.

Comment: Most likely your threads took an exception somewhere in their long running operation and were terminated.

Comment: I think that your English is good enough, but your question should be answerable. In particular, it is not clear what the "join" method of Engine does, or the "Engine" class itself. To me it all looks like some sort of long running spider/monitor. If that's the case, you should perhaps program defensively and expect your program to shut down suddenly from time to time, and while you should strive to fix your bugs there, I think that some will be  unavoidable (e.g., server shutdowns, processes evicted for memory over-consumption in shared environments, network errors, etc.).

Comment: stop changing the default encoding...this is BAD STYLE

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!!! I have catched all exceptions in the program,but it didn't catch anyone. And the "join" method is the method of the module "threading" in the python which use for waiting sub thread quit. And I set the default encoding in the program because I want to let all the program use the 'utf-8' encoding,the encoding problem has caused a lot of bug.

Comment: Hi,I think I found the resason. I check the winserver2003's log which show me python.exe encounter an application error,the error module is etree.pyd which is from lxml-2.3.win32-py2.6.I change the lxml's version,the error doesn't happen again in these days.